# BackgroundAgent not working in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

When I upgraded Windows Phone 8 application to Windows Phone 8.1. My `BackgroundAgent` stopped working.

I have registered it in `WMAppManifest` file as same I had done in Windows Phone 8.But when I call LaunchForTest in debug mode it gives me an error `Agent Not Found`.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'AutoUploadAgent' doesn't exist
   at Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(String name, TimeSpan delay)
```

Please help me

Comment: http://firstfloorsoftware.com/Media/DiffLists/Windows%20Phone%208.1%20%28Silverlight%29-vs-Windows%20Phone%208.1.html... you can visit this link and check here that which namespaces are now not supported in windows phone 8.1 over to windows phone 8....

Answer (score 1):

I hope below link will help you...
http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/23/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-multitasking-and-background-tasks/...